# Sumif vs Sumifs in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

here is my understanding on sum functions:

Sumifs do not accept multiple columns in sum_range but Sumif do, is that correct?

if it is, could you please suggest an alternative to include multiple columns for sum range. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `SUMIFS` only allow a sum of one column, much like `SUMIF`. 
The difference is in the number of *criteria* ranges.
In a SUMIFS, you would say

```
=SUMIFS(sum range, criteria range 1, criteria 1, criteria range 2, criteria 2, ...)
```

If you want to sum multiple columns, you can add multiple `SUMIFS`es:

```
=SUMIFS(...) + SUMIFS(...) + SUMIFS(...)
```

Comment: Got it thank you! But Sumif does use multiple columns in the sum_range like =sumif(range1,criteria1,A1:C10). It does work. But when I try to sum A1:C10 in Sumifs it does not work. Thanks for providing alternative solution.

Comment: @Srekk While SUMIF will allow you to place 3 columns in a range, I don't believe it actually sums each column together for appropriate rows. Try this out yourself to confirm that it actually does what you think it does. As a side-note, I prefer to *always* use SUMIFS, COUNTIFS, AVERAGEIFS etc., rather than their singular counterparts, because it is more expandable and puts the 'summing'/'counting' etc. column at the front at all times.